# Is an upsert in mongodb atomic with the filter and the actual update

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document I want to upsert. It has a unique index on one of the properties, so I have something like this to ensure I get no collisions

```
var barVal = 1;

collection.UpdateOne(
     x=>x.Bar == barVal,
     new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Foo>().Set(x=>x.Bar, barVal),  
     new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

But I seem to sometimes get collisions from this on the unique index on bar.

**Is mongo atomic around upserts, so if the filter matches the document cant be changed before the update completes?**

If it is I probably have a problem somewhere else, if its not I need to handle the fact its not.

The docs don't seem to sugguest that this is one way or the other.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 5):

Actually, docs says something about this. Here is what I found in [db.collection.update#use-unique-indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes)

> To avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use `upsert:
>   true` if the query field is **uniquely indexed**.
>
> ...
>
> With a unique index, if multiple applications issue the same update
>   with `upsert: true`, exactly one `update()` would successfully insert a
>   new document.
>
> The remaining operations would either:
>
> - update the newly inserted document, or
> - fail when they attempted to insert a duplicate.
>     If the operation fails because of a duplicate index key error,
>     applications may retry the operation which will succeed as an update
>     operation.

So, if you have created a unique index on the field you are querying, it is guaranteed that the insertion is "atomic" and a sort of rollback is performed if a failure occures.

Comment: what if the filter is time based? for example: createdDate>18:00:00PM, how can I do this atomically? I tried it and it is not atomic because of my filter criteria

Comment: @YahyaHussein are you sure that is the problem? Did you index the field correctly?

Comment: Please refer to this question and read comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961674/atomic-if-not-exist-then-insert-in-mongodb-net-driver