# Atomic if not exist then insert in Mongodb .Net driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, atomic

Let us say I have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And I have N threads that perform "if not exists then insert", how can I ensure that only one thread inserts a document in DB.

What I tried is:

```
 void test(DBContext context)
    {

        var person = new Person() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "name", Title = "title", ReceivedAt = DateTime.Now };
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        var update = Builders<Person>.Update.Combine(
              Builders<Person>.Update.SetOnInsert(y => y.Name, person.Name)
            , Builders<Person>.Update.SetOnInsert(y => y.Title, person.Title)
            , Builders<Person>.Update.SetOnInsert(y => y.ReceivedAt, person.ReceivedAt)
            , Builders<Person>.Update.SetOnInsert(y => y.Id, person.Id));
        var result = context.People.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<Person>(
            x => x.Title == person.Title && x.Name == person.Name && x.ReceivedAt > person.ReceivedAt - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            update,
            new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Person>() { IsUpsert = true,ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.Before}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (result?.Id != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("duplicate");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("first time");
        }
    }
```

And tested it using:

```
DBContext context = new DBContext ();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   Task.Run(() => test(context));
  }
```

But the above code inserts more than one document to collection, seems like `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` is not atomic.

Is there a way to achieve that only one thread inserts a document into collection in Mongodb?

Comment: Seems okay to me. Try to use UpdateOne instead, and check the UpdateResult for number of matched and modified documents.

Comment: the current code prints "first time" 3 to 6 times

Comment: @AlexBlex UpdateOne gave the same result, more than one document is inserted to DB

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes. It must be the `$gte` condition generated from `x.ReceivedAt > person.ReceivedAt - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` doesn't play well with the unique index, which works with exact match only.

Comment: I am using .Net driver, is there a way to override this issue?

Comment: It is on the db side. Language/driver agnostic.

Comment: I c, and there is no way to override it?

Comment: Did you try creating a unique index without leaning on `FindOneAndUpdateAsync`?

Comment: I need a time based query, how can I do that with unique index? I am not sure what you mean by unique index, as I have a guid index already

Comment: The `_id` field is automatically uniquely indexed by default. You can uniquely index your field to guarantee that no duplicates are present. You are not limited to 1.

Comment: and how would I include time in id? so where I need to get a query I get it by Id not by time?

Comment: Wait, indexing is different from primary key. Read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Answer (score 0):

You need a unique index.  What is your model's purpose?  Do you want one record for a person and ReceivedAt is the last time they were "received" or is this more like an event each time they were "received" should be here once?
Create a unique index on either (Name,Title) or (Name,Title,ReceivedAt).
Since DateTime.Now is going to increment while running, you are going to see multiple "first time" in the second case.  In the first case, you should change the ReceivedAt from SetOnInsert to just Set.